# How to mute or select only one audio channel?

Tags: c#, audio, audio-channels

I'd know how can I mute or select only one audio channel in C#. I have to play an audio file only in the left/right channel. Is it possible? What do I have to do?

Comment: Please provide some more details and code. How do you play your audio file so far?

Comment: i'm using System.Media SoundPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to use the Balance property of System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.

[MSDN MediaPlayer Balance Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.balance(v=vs.110).aspx)

Set it to -1 for the left and 1 for the right channel.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(@"C:\temp\Kalimba.mp3"));

        if (DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Balance = 1;
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.Balance = -1;
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide me a sample code? I need to create an audio player and select the channel (it depends on the time), then play the audio. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[System.Media.SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) lacks the possability of adjusting the balance. You should try something different. System.Media.SoundPlayer simply *controls playback of a sound from a .wav file*